# trigger function in child.vue after clicking button in parent.vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, components

I'm working with `BootstrapVue`.

I have a method in my `parent.vue` where I pass a value (`this.propsIndex`) to my `child.vue`.

Now I want to use this `value` each time it will be clicked in a method of my child.vue - but how can I trigger my function and make it working?

Thank You very much!

**If it's possible I want to avoid using `watch`**

my parent.vue

```
<template>
  <div v-for="(id, index) in inputs" :key="index">
    <b-button @click="deleteViaIndex(index)">Delete</b-button>
    <child :indexProps="indexProps" />
  </div>

  <div>
    <b-button @click="addInput()">Add Input</b-button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  methods: {
    deleteViaIndex(index) {
      this.propsIndex= index;
    },

    addInput() {
      this.inputs.push({})
    },
  },

  data() {
    return {
      inputs: [{}],
      propsIndex: '',
    }
  }
</script>
```

my child.vue (script)

```
props: ["propsIndex"],

methods: {
  deleteViaParentIndex() {
    //HERE I WANT TO USE IT EVERY TIME IT WILL BE CLICKED IN MY PARENT.VUE
    //BUT FOR NOW IT'S NOT DOING ANYTHING WHEN I CONSOLE.LOG(this.propsIndex)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a naming mismatch. In a child component, you have a prop `propsIndex`, yet in a parent template you are passing `indexProps`.

When passing props, you have to remember, that prop name is always in the first part, and the value you are passing should go next. https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Passing-Static-or-Dynamic-Props

Furthermore, since HTML attribute names are case-insensitive, you should pass a prop this way:

```
<child :props-index="indexProps" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the naming mismatch mentioned by Marcin, you can access a child component from a parent component using a [ref](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-template-refs.html) in the template:

`<child ref="childrenComponents" :props-index="propsIndex" />`

Since you have multiple of the child components inside a `v-for`, this makes the `childrenComponents` in `$refs` an array of components. To call `deleteViaParentIndex` on all of them, you need to iterate through them:

```
deleteViaIndex(index) {
    this.propsIndex = index;
    this.$refs.childrenComponents.forEach(child => child.deleteViaParentIndex());
}
```

There's one more optimization you can make.

Since you're using `propsIndex` only to pass an index that the child component uses, and you already have the index as a param in `deleteViaIndex`, you can simply pass that to the child as a param during the `deleteViaParentIndex` function call, thus removing the need for the `propsIndex` data altogether:

in `parent.vue`:

```
deleteViaIndex(index) {
    this.$refs.childrenComponents.forEach(child => child.deleteViaParentIndex(index));
}
```

in `child.vue`:

```
deleteViaParentIndex(index) {
    // operations using index
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for trying to help me out - but at least I get following error ```Property 'each' does not exist on type 'Vue | Element | (Vue | Element)[]'.
  Property 'each' does not exist on type 'Vue'```

Comment: I think the problem ist that ```each```, ```forEach```,...  only working through arrays.. and because of that I think I can't use it here..

Comment: also get this in my console: ```[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: this.$refs.childrenComponents.each is not a function"```

Comment: @patrick96 you're right, I mixed up my libraries in my head. `childrenComponents` should be an array, so you should be able to use `forEach` instead of `each`.